# FindControl is not working as expected?

Tags: c#, asp.net, findcontrol

I have this structure :

```
Page
 |
 +---Ascx
      |
      +---<div  runat="server">
                    |
                    +---<asp:button>
```

I already  know that `Findcontrol` *doesn't* work recursively .

However when I pressed the button and went to debug and wrote :

`this.FindControl("btn1")` it **did** find the `"button"`

**But**

- `this`= the ascx
- There is a `div runat server` which wraps the button

So *how* did it find it ? According to the definition , it doesn't suppose to work.

Msdn :

> **Control.FindControl**   --> The method does not search throughout a hierarchy of controls within
>   controls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3118364/859154).

**Only** controls which  inherits from `TemplateControl`, which implements the `INamingContainer` interface.

and obviously  `<div runat server>` is not one of them.

i.e. `UserControl`  :

```
public class UserControl : TemplateControl, IAttributeAccessor, INonBindingContainer, INamingContainer, IUserControlDesignerAccessor
{...}
```

i.e. `ContentPlaceHolder`:

```
public class ContentPlaceHolder : Control, INonBindingContainer, INamingContainer
{...}
```

and here I can see all those controls :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The asp.net have a **different tree struct than the actually DOM of html page.**

The controls on the same page are like on the same branch of the tree. So all the controls on the same page can be found by searching the page. The controls that are inside some custom control are also all together.

Comment: if div would have been another user control , it would'nt find it.( and I know that it is a different tree obviously :-)  , it's just that according to the definition - it is control under control

Comment: @RoyiNamir Yes this is what I say you, the tree of the asp.net is not the same as the html tree. Imaging them as modules. Each module have their branch on the tree. One module is the page, one other is a custom control. asp.net works with some kind of modules that work together to render the page.

Comment: So which server controls open a new "module"( as  you say) ?